# What is the difference between Probabilistic Graphical models and Graph Neural networks?

Tags: comparison, graph-neural-networks, probabilistic-graphical-models, probabilistic-machine-learning

While going over PGMs and GNNs, it seems like both leverage the graph data structure. The former has been used to represent causal associations (among other things), while the latter has a varied set of applications. Do these techniques intersect?